# When setting ColorOrder in Matlab, first point doesn't change color

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

I'm plotting cell arrays against each other and I want certain groups of points to have the same color. I made a new color order matrix and all the points changed to the correct color EXCEPT the very first one. It's stuck on the default blueish color.

The variables are contained in cells so I'm looping through to make the figure.

```
C = [1 0 0; 1 0 0; 1 0 0; 1 0 0;...
0 1 1; 0 1 1;...
1 1 0; 1 1 0; 1 1 0; 1 1 0];

for k = 1:numFiles
hold all
plot(zonal{k}, deltaT{k},'*','MarkerSize',11);
set(gca,'ColorOrder',C);
end
```

C contains the correct number of rgb triplets. Is this an easy fix that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `ColorOrder` *before* the first call to `plot()`.

```
C = [1 0 0; 1 0 0; 1 0 0; 1 0 0;...
0 1 1; 0 1 1;...
1 1 0; 1 1 0; 1 1 0; 1 1 0];

axes()
set(gca,'ColorOrder',C);
hold all

for k = 1:numFiles
plot(zonal{k}, deltaT{k},'*','MarkerSize',11);
end

hold off
```

`plot()` will then examine the (fixed) value of `ColorOrder` each time `plot()` is called and iterate through its values.